# Java stream equivalent in ruby?

Tags: java, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to convert the following Java selenium code to Ruby selenium code

```
  List<String> items = myDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")) //This returns an array
            .stream().map(WebElement::getText)  //Calls stream map 
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am stuck on the part where it converts the array to stream and maps it with WebElement getText and converts to a list

This is what I have tried

```
 items = driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]").map(&:text)
```

I can't seem to find the ruby equivalent of the stream and .collect? What could I do here?

Comment: Which HTML parser are you intending on using? `map` and `collect` are available in Ruby.

Comment: I am not quite what you mean by HTML parser? The above given java code works but the ruby code doesn't store anything in the items array. How could I use collect also? @tadman

Answer (score -2):

The equivalent to a Java `Stream` is an [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html). There is no equivalent to [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) in Ruby. [Java's `collect` is a generalization of folding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction), Ruby has two folding operations: [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) and [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-each_with_object), both of which are special cases of Java's `collect`. The equivalent to calling `stream()` to create a `Stream` is to call `each` without a block to create an `Enumerator`.

However, if you want the full generality of `collect` available in Ruby, you will have to implement it yourself.